# Setter in Guzzle 5 is not allowed in Guzzle6

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm using Guzzle to make tests on the API i'm working on in Symfony2.

I've been watching the knpUniversity series on Rest, and i have trouble updating the part where i should be able to use the app_test.php instead of app.php.
In the series, they use Guzzle v5, but in v6 there are major changes [with PSR7 use](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#migrating-to-middleware)

In the tutorial, to permit the use of another uri ending with other than app.php, [they use](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest/test-database#properly-prefixing-all-uris) :

```
use GuzzleHttp\Event\BeforeEvent;
... 
class ApiTestCase extends KernelTestCase
{
... 
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        $baseUrl = getenv('TEST_BASE_URL');
        self::$staticClient = new Client([
            'base_url' => $baseUrl,
            'defaults' => [
                'exceptions' => false
            ]
        ]);
        ...
        // guaranteeing that /app_test.php is prefixed to all URLs
        self::$staticClient->getEmitter()
            ->on('before', function(BeforeEvent $event) {
                $path = $event->getRequest()->getPath();
                if (strpos($path, '/api') === 0) {
                    $event->getRequest()->setPath('/app_test.php'.$path);
                }
            });
        self::bootKernel();
    }
```

But with Guzzle6, there is no setter for the request :

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;


class ApiTestCase extends KernelTestCase
{
    private static $staticClient;

    protected $client;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        //defined in phpunit.xml
        $baseUri = getenv('TEST_BASE_URI');

        //Create a handler stack that has all of the default middlewares attached
        $handler = HandlerStack::create();

        // guaranteeing that /app_test.php is prefixed to all URLs
        $handler->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {
            $path = $request->getUri()->getPath();
            if (strpos($path, '/api') === 0) {
                $request->getUri()->setPath('/app_test.php'.$path);  // <-- this is not allowed
            }
            // Notice that we have to return a request object
            return $request->withHeader('X-Foo', 'Bar');
        }));

        // Inject the handler into the client
        self::$staticClient = new Client([
            'base_uri' => $baseUri.'/app_test.php',
            'handler' => $handler,
            'defaults' => [
                'http_errors' => false
            ]
        ]);

        //Allows to use service container
        self::bootKernel();
    }
```

So how can i change the uri, to use the app_test.php instead of app.php ?

Thanks

===========================

EDIT : 
Actually, they give [a solution](https://gist.github.com/weaverryan/72d529bac4fb5c4892d98b6c57e45ca5#file-apitestcase-php-L48) in one of the post of the comment

```
$handler->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function(RequestInterface $request) {
    $path = $request->getUri()->getPath();
    if (strpos($path, '/app_test.php') !== 0) {
        $path = '/app_test.php' . $path;
    }
    $uri = $request->getUri()->withPath($path);
    return $request->withUri($uri);
}));
```

Thanks @Cerad

Comment: I would think something like $request =  $request->getUri()->withPath() would work.  Might need to get the uri object and then use $request->withUri().

Comment: `
      $handler->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {
            $path = $request->getUri()->getPath();
            if (strpos($path, '/api/v1') === 0) {
                $uri = $request->getUri()->withPath('/app_test.php'.$path);
                $request->withUri($uri);
            }
            var_dump($request->getUri()->getPath());

            return $request->withHeader('X-Foo', 'Bar');
        }));
 `
still displays the uri without the prefix.